# Use of uninitialized value in string

Tags: perl, param, scalar

Use of uninitialized value in string 
Where is mistake?

```
else{
    print $q->param('test_name');

    my $age = $q->param('age');

    print "Возраст: $age";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error (based on the code you posted) would indicate that there is no parameter being sent to the script named either of `test_name` or `age`.

Answer (score 2):

You should include the full error message in your posts.

The following script will output two warnings:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print undef;

my $age = undef;

print "Label: $age";
```

Outputs:

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at script.pl line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $age in concatenation (.) or string at script.pl line 8.
Label:
```

As you can observe, if your warning is about an `uninitialized value in a print`, then test_name is not defined.  If it's about an `uninitialized value in concatenation`, then age is not defined.

Additionally, your warning messages should state the exact line number that it is referring to.  Even if you don't understand the precise meaning of a warning, this tells you where to look.